# Menu with Text only not showing in Toolbar

Tags: android, text, menu, toolbar

I have to show back icon, Logo and text (Next) in Toolbar. Next is right aligned. I tried placing text via menu. I have set logo and back button to toolbar.

```
toolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.logo);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.back);
```

Also, I have inflated following menu in onCreateOptionsMenu

Menu inflated:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_next"
    android:title="@string/next"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Text Menu is not visible at all. if I put icon in menu item, it gets displayed.
I have used android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.

**Edited:**

I solved it. In case  someone else gets struck with such issue.

Please add

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/blue</item>
```

in styles. Menu itemw as getting selected on click but was not visible, means it was showing white text color on white toolbar. Setting menuText color solved my problem.

Comment: i think your toolbar logo and navigation icon taking lots of space .. have you added `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`?

Comment: if you are using white toolbar then why using theme as dark... if you use light theme menu text becomes black thats the best solution

Comment: I have used light theme. But had specified colorPrimary as white which was being used at somewhere.

Comment: @seema I think you should post your solution as answer and accept it. I had the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html) explains that the `withText` option for `showAsAction` will

> Also include the title text (defined by android:title) with the action item.

Since that is what you want, code the following.

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_next"
android:title="@string/next"
app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
```

Comment: Thanks, its resolved by adding menu text color in styles. It working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

First, remove default title in your Activity:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Then, your toolbar layout can be like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/material_blue"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```

And, in your activity handle the click event:

```
toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Clicked");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing to support widget. This worked for me

```
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

This what it looked after the change

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        tools:context=".AppHome.HomeActivity"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an empty action with no text but blank space in it,
it might happen if you have created your own tool bar in the layout and have also used the Action bar in your theme's parent.
If you are creating your own toolbar then use `parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"` in your themes, both normal and night themes.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because of the style used in your layout.

To solve this, define a new style and use it in your layout.

```
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:itemBackground">#fff</item>  // background color of the menus
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>// text color of the  menus
</style>
```

Use it like this in your layout

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light"
    android:background="@color/primary_pink"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    />
```